# Specializing a class for iterators convertable to pointers

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers, specialization

I am attempting to develop a class that will allow me to efficiently access a container/pointer via iterator semantics when it can be done correctly, and when the iterators cannot be converted to pointers I want to copy the iterator range to a temporary buffer and return that pointer instead. To do this I've written the following program:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>

// General case copies data to temporary vector, in case iterators are from a list or otherwise.
template < typename Iterator, typename tag = std::iterator_traits < Iterator >::iterator_category >
class IteratorBuffer
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits < Iterator >::value_type T;

    std::vector < T > temp;
public:
    IteratorBuffer(Iterator begin, Iterator end) : temp(std::distance(begin, end)) 
    { 
        std::copy(begin, end, temp.begin()); 
    } 

    const T * data() { return temp.data(); }
};

// Special case should be invoked if Iterator can safely be treated as a pointer to the range.
template < typename Iterator >
class IteratorBuffer < Iterator, std::random_access_iterator_tag >
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits < Iterator >::value_type T;

    const T * temp;
public:
    IteratorBuffer(Iterator begin, Iterator end) : temp(&*begin) { }

    const T * data() { return temp; }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::vector < int > test1(10);
    IteratorBuffer < std::vector < int >::iterator > temp1(test1.begin(), test1.end());
    // This should be pointing to the data in test1.
    assert(temp1.data() == test1.data());

    std::list < int > test2;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        test2.push_back(i);
    IteratorBuffer < std::list < int >::iterator > temp2(test2.begin(), test2.end());
    // This must not point to the beginning iterator.
    assert(temp2.data() != &*test2.begin());

    int test3[10];
    IteratorBuffer < int * > temp3(&test3[0], &test3[10]);
    // This should point to the array.
    assert(temp3.data() == &test3[0]);

    std::deque < int > test4;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        test4.push_back(i);
    IteratorBuffer < std::deque < int >::iterator > temp4(test4.begin(), test4.end());
    // This must not point to the beginning iterator, not safe.
    assert(temp4.data() != &*test4.begin());
}
```

This fails the last test, because std::deque's iterators have random_access_iterator_tag.

How do I write this class such that it works correctly in general?

I suppose I should mention I'm using VC++ 2010.

Edit: As Adam says (I was afraid of this) this is not directly possible. Now, I am attempting to define my own traits which enable me to do this. See my attempt below:

```
template < typename Iterator >
struct IteratorTraits 
{ 
    enum { IsPointerCompatible = false }; 
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits < Iterator >::value_type T;
};
template < typename T >
struct IteratorTraits < T * > 
{ 
    enum { IsPointerCompatible = true }; 
    typedef T T;
};
template < typename T >
struct IteratorTraits < const T * > 
{ 
    enum { IsPointerCompatible = true }; 
    typedef const T T;
};
//template < typename T >
//struct IteratorTraits < typename std::vector < T >::iterator > 
//{ 
//  enum { IsPointerCompatible = true };
//  typedef T T;
//};
//template < typename T, size_t N >
//struct IteratorTraits < typename std::array < T, N >::iterator > 
//{ 
//  enum { IsPointerCompatible = true };
//  typedef T T;
//};
```

I've omitted the IteratorBuffer classes because they are very similar to the ones using std::iterator_traits.

The first two specializations work, but two commented traits structs will not work. How do I write these such that it will work, without being dependent on my particular STL implementation?

Comment: `&*test2.begin()` looks ugly!

Comment: Its ugly but it works...

Comment: This is not really possible I'm afraid. The only possibility is to specialize for specific iterators such as `vector<T>::iterator`. Note that `vector<T>::reverse_iterator` is not safe.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for your comment, see my edits about specialization for particular iterator classes.

Comment: In your specializations, `Iterator` is not defined (the definition in the main template is not in scope). You need to define it again: `typedef typename std::vector <T>::iterator Iterator;`. By the way, `typedef T T` looks a bit strange, though not incorrect AFAICT. I would use different identifiers anyway.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, you are right, but that is not the problem that prevents this from working. Even if you correct that issue, the problem is the same: the compiler says it cannot deduce type T. I've fixed the code in my post.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is non-deducible context. Perhaps you need to take `T` from `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type`, or something similar. Sorry, cannot check it from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can specialize for pointers explicitly and then for any containers (that you know of) which iterators can be treated that way (which is the case with `std::vector`). This isn't that bad since there is not general "trait" of a container that would say that its iterators can be used as pointers. It is a guarantee the container provider must make explicitly.

---

Note also that the general version of `IteratorBuffer` silently assumes at least forward iterator category and will fail with input-only iterators (as it uses the range twice).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See my edits, I'm attempting to implement what you describe but I am stumped on how to define the specialization for particular iterator classes.

Comment: I tried and I failed. Believing there is no reasonable and Standard-compiliant solution. But I will try some more and if I will find anything I will post it here.